# Error when using relative paths for hyperlink

Tags: arcgis-desktop, hyperlink

I'm trying to create a hyperlink to images related to objects within an attribute table.

I can get this working fine using absolute paths however I'm getting problems when I try and use relative paths. When I try and open a hyperlink from a relative path I get a message saying:

> Unable to open "Images\boulder1.jpg" Please make sure the path is
>   correct and the document exists.

My images are contained within a folder called "Images" and this folder is in the same folder as the mxd.

I've been using this [website](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/supplement/pathnames-explained-absolute-relative-unc-and-url.htm) to ensure I have the correct relative path for my images. I've tried different ways of pathing to my images "..\Images" ".\Images" etc but I keep getting the same error.

I've tried putting the relative path in the hyperlink base option of map document properties and in the attribute and neither is working.

Also I have store relative pathnames to data sources ticked on. Although I'm not sure if this makes a difference if I'm not moving the mxd.

Does anyone know why I am getting this error and how to solve it?

Comment: The path to a folder called images in the same location as a page referencing the folder would be `images/`

Comment: Can you specify the exact steps that you are following in a numbered list with more detail, please?  That way a potential answerer may be more easily attracted to try and reproduce what you are describing.